# How to display only part of a control by either hiding\clipping?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, graphics, user-controls

I have a control derived from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl which is placed in a customized grid. When the first column of the grid is frozen and the grid is scrolled by a few pixels, the second column becomes partially visible such that the control in this column also becomes partially visible.

To achieve this I want to be able to display only the part of the control that is visible either by hiding/clipping the left portion of the control.

I don’t want to modify OnPaint of the control as I don’t have access to the control’s code. I can change the code in the grid where the control is displayed.

I tried the following which didn’t work:
1. Invalidating only part of the control that has to be visible.
2. Using GraphicsPath as follows:

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath controlPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
controlPath.AddRectangle(visibleRect);
editControl.Region = new Region(controlPath);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: You have to intercept the painting of the control so you can modify Graphics.Clip.  Derive you own class from it and override OnPaintBackground and OnPaint.  That will not work if this is a UserControl that contains other controls.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But in my case I have many types of controls that can be placed in the grid and hence deriving a new control from the existing one for all controls would not be feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working solution:

Using *GraphicsPath* worked. I wasn’t setting the clip rectangle properly due to which I couldn’t see the clipping happen. Instead of setting the xOffset of the clip region wrt to the Grid I had to set the clip region wrt to the control.
The window region is a collection of pixels within the window where the operating system permits drawing. The operating system does not display any portion of a window that lies outside of the window region. The coordinates of a control's region are relative to the upper-left corner of the control, not the client area of the control( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy6052(vs.71).aspx)